# Smallest field containing $F$ and $a \in K$

Tags: field-theory

Definition. Given a field extension $K \supset F$ and an element $a \in K,$ define $F(a)$ to be the intersection of all subfields of $K$ that contain $F$ and $a.$

What is some more explicit notation for this field? I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: It is all expressions $f(a)/g(a)$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are in $F[x]$ and $g(a) \not= 0$.

Comment: God no, just try an *actual example*.  Take $F = \mathbf Q$, $K = \mathbf R$, and $a = \sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example. $K=\mathbb C$, $F=\mathbb Q$, $a=\sqrt[3]{2}.$ Then $F(a)$ is going to be the smallest field containing $F$ and $a$, from your definition. So here, as $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \supseteq \mathbb Q$, $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \ni \sqrt[3]{2}$, we have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \supseteq \{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}|a, b \in \mathbb Q\}$. But this isn't yet a field, as it's not closed under multiplication; $\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^2\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2})$. So we get $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) \supseteq \left\{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^2|a, b,c \in \mathbb Q\right\}.$ It is now an exercise to check that this is closed under $+$ and $\times$ - so it's a ring - and then since any ring that is finite dimensional as a vector space is a field, we get that the R.H.S is a field so $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{2}) = \left\{a+b\sqrt[3]{2}+c\left(\sqrt[3]{2}\right)^2|a, b,c \in \mathbb Q\right\}$